# Code 400 - Resource collection filtering error in Magento Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, magento-1.9

This is the code I've used before and it was working fun but now i have received an error saying `"{\"messages\":{\"error\":[{\"code\":400,\"message\":\"Resource collection filtering error.\"}]}}"`

```
                FilterExpression filterex = new FilterExpression("status", ExpressionOperator.@in, "Pending");
                filterex.FieldName = "status";
                filterex.FieldValue = "processing";
                filterex.ExpressionOperator = ExpressionOperator.@in;
                Filter filter = new Filter();
                filter.PageSize = 10;
                filter.FilterExpressions.Add(filterex);
```

This is the URL:

```
{http://sample.test.com/api/rest/orders?filter[0][attribute]=status&filter[0][in]=processing&limit=10}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that System => Web Service => REST Attributes was configured for your user.

This worked for me.

Source: https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi/issues/36